# Replace file content in Kotlin DSL

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I want to create gradle task which is replace my imports. I have created this so far.

```
val replaceImports by creating(Copy::class) {
    val dir = "${project.buildDir}/generated-sources/xjc/com/test/dto/"
    from(dir){
        include("TestSourceClass.java")
        filter{ line -> line.replace("package com.test;","package com.test;\n\nimport com.test2.AaaClass;")}
    }
    into(dir)
}
```

This code works only if the `from` and `into` is different directory.

Comment: doesn't it suffice to just do the following here: `dir.walk().filter { /* if that should be a filter */ it.name == "TestSourceClass.java" }.forEach { it.writeText(it.readText().replace(....)) }`? It's generated code after all... but the more interesting question is probably: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: maybe you are also interested in schema bindings instead?

Comment: maybe you also need to wrap such a code as shown above into a `doLast {`...

Comment: With your first solution its working. But `doLast` didn't help.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. Added the first comment as an answer. I used the `doLast` once in combination with another task to ensure that it is called at the end of that task... thought you may require something like that too...

Answer (score 1):

As also mentioned in the comments and as it worked, you can do the following instead:

```
val replaceImports by creating(Copy::class) {
  dir.walk()
     .filter { /* if that should be a filter */ it.name == "TestSourceClass.java" }
     .forEach { it.writeText(it.readText().replace("package com.test;","package com.test;\n\nimport com.test2.AaaClass;")) }
}
```

Note that you may also be interested in schema bindings, depending on how you generate your code. Scanning through all the files that are just previously generated to adapt them again may not really be the fastest choice, whereas giving the generator the appropriate bindings will already generate you the code as required.